# Grails mongodb plugin configuration

Tags: mongodb, grails, groovy

I use grails 2.5 and setup [mongodb plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/mongodb). And there is the problem: when I try to save next object using console - all is ok, and empty strings saving as empty strings:

```
User {
    name: "Hary",
    lastname: ""
}
```

But when I try to save the same object via Idea using plugin listed above, it returns next:

```
 User {
    name: "Hary",
    lastname: null
}
```

I understand, that mongodb plugin can converts empty strings to null, but I can't find solution for this problem.

Anyone know how can I solve it? Thanks!